# Open Register Tab of Ajax Login Pop-up

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, popup, popupmenu

I've got this login link of this WP Theme which opens an ajax pop-up to either login or register. The theme has only Login button but I want to add another button - Register.
I've added the button and eveything works except that the pop-up form opens up in the default tab , which is Log-in.
There is another tab on the form - Register but how can I open the pop-up to that tab I have no idea. I've tried several things but nothing works.
I'm pretty sure this is really simple but sometimes one gets stuck...

The first Regsiter button has a code like this :

```
<div class="account logged-out" id="reg-btn">
 <a id="reg-clck" href="#popup-form" class="btn-login-register">Register</a>
</div>
```

and the Register tab in the pop-up form looks like this:

```
<div class="tabs-form">
 <a class="btn-login" href="#ux-login" data-form="ux-login">Log in</a>
 <a class="btn-register active" href="#ux-register" data-form="ux-register">Sign Up</a>
 <div class="loading-effect"><span class="civi-dual-ring"></span></div>
</div>
```

The Register button opens up the pop-up but how to go forward and click the Register Tab in the form ?

Thanks in advance!
Have a good weekend!